# bug in ionic official ToDo example

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic's official ToDo example (http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html) seems to have the bug that the modal that pops up asking for a Project name has "index.html" displayed on top of "Project name" for the iOS version but Android does not have this distracting "index.html" displayed. Why is this and how can I get rid of the "index.html" in the iOS version?
[image: distracting "index.html" on top of "Project name"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official Ionic forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-alert-box-title-shows-index-html-how-to-remove/5730) they suggest that you use the [cordova dialog plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.dialogs).

But, I would instead use the built in [$ionicPopup service](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/).